# Wants to disable right click event on submenu, extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, menu, submenu

I have a menu which has submenu also. Wants to disable the right click event

On menu it is working. I mean if I right click then nothing happens but same is not applying for submenus

Tried

```
{
    text: 'Tools',
    name: 'toolsBtn',
    id:'toolsmenu',
    disabled:true,
    menu: new Ext.menu.Menu({
        id:'menutoolbar',
        items: [{
            text: 'Select some row from the results grid',
        }],
        listeners: {
            render : {
                fn : function(item) {
                    var el = item.getEl();
                    this.el.on("contextmenu", Ext.emptyFn, this, {preventDefault: true});
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Its working on Menu but not on submenu

Comment: I am afraid nobody understands your question. Can you explain?

Comment: i have a menu which has submenu also. Wants to disable the right click event.

Comment: on menu its working.. i mean if i click right click then nothing happened but same is not applying for submenus

Answer (score 0):

Just add the same listener on your sub-menu:

```
items: [{
        text: 'Select some row from the results grid',
        listeners: { //your listener
        }
    }]
```